# Override ref value in smallrye microprofile using custom OASFilter in quarkus application

Tags: openapi, quarkus, smallrye, eclipse-microprofile-config

I'm trying to override ref value in schema for microprofile health check API in quarkus application. I followed the below link [Smallrye open api interceptor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65860644/smallrye-open-api-interceptor) and created a custom filter which overrides OASFilter. But, the ref value is not picking the new ref value from the filter.

```
@Override
public APIResponse filterAPIResponse(APIResponse apiResponse) {
    if (apiResponse.getRef()=="#/components/schemas/HealthCheckResponse")
    {
        String ref = "#components/schemas/microProfile";
        apiResponse.setRef(ref);
    }

    return apiResponse;
}
```

Basically, I need to add description to each property inside a schema.

Existing schema:

```yaml
HealthCheckResponse:
  type: object
  properties:
    data:
      type: object
      nullable: true
    name:
      type: string
    status:
      $ref: '#/components/schemas/HealthCheckStatus'
HealthCheckStatus:
  enum:
  - DOWN
  - UP
  type: string
```

Expected schema change:

```yaml
microProfile:
  description: microprofile response
  type: object
  properties:
    data:
      description: "Information of the service. If the service is down, this holds\
        \ the information of why it is failed."
      type: object
    name:
      description: 'Service Name '
      type: string
    status:
      description: 'Service Status '
      type: string
```

I added the property mp.openapi.filter= custom filter name in application.properties file. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Possibly unrelated: The `String ref = "#components/...` line should be `String ref = "#/components/...` - that is, it needs a `/` after `#`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 ways that I am aware off:

---

---

**You can programmatically create your own custom schema and reference it.**

In this case, the Schema is created programmatically, and does not have to exist anywhere in your openapi.yaml file.

```
    void updateHealthStatusRefWithProgrammaticSchema(OpenAPI openAPI) {

        openAPI.getPaths().getPathItems().forEach((String pathName, PathItem pathItem) -> {
            if (pathName.equalsIgnoreCase("/health-check")) {

                Schema dynamicSchema = OASFactory.createSchema().title("Programmatic-MicroProfile").description("dynamic-schema-description").type(Schema.SchemaType.OBJECT).properties(Map.of("custom-field-data", OASFactory.createSchema().description("Information of the service. If the service is down, this holds the information of why it is failed.").type(Schema.SchemaType.OBJECT)));
                openAPI.getComponents().addSchema("Dynamic-MicroProfile", dynamicSchema);

                pathItem.getGET().getResponses().getAPIResponse("200").getContent().getMediaType("application/json").setSchema(dynamicSchema);
            }
        });
    }
```

[image]

---

---

**You can have a defined Static Schema in your openapi.yaml which you can reference programmatically.**

In this case, the schema must exist in your openapi.yaml file, as you can see we are searching for it by doing `get()`**

```
    void updateHealthStatusRefByUsingStaticSchema(OpenAPI openAPI) {

        openAPI.getPaths().getPathItems().forEach((String pathName, PathItem pathItem) -> {
            if (pathName.equalsIgnoreCase("/health-check")) {
                Schema staticMicroProfileSchema = openAPI.getComponents().getSchemas().get("Static-MicroProfile");
                pathItem.getGET().getResponses().getAPIResponse("200").getContent().getMediaType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).setSchema(staticMicroProfileSchema);
            }
        });
    }
```

[image]

---

---

You update the openapi.yaml only if you want to have a Static Schema already defined.

**openapi.yaml**

```
components:
  schemas:
      HealthCheckResponse:
        type: object
        properties:
          data:
            type: object
            nullable: true
          name:
            type: string
          status:
            $ref: '#/components/schemas/HealthCheckStatus'
      HealthCheckStatus:
        enum:
          - DOWN
          - UP
        type: string
      Static-MicroProfile:
        description: microprofile response
        type: object
        properties:
          data:
            description: "Information of the service. If the service is down, this holds\
              \ the information of why it is failed."
            type: object
          name:
            description: 'Service Name '
            type: string
          status:
            description: 'Service Status '
            type: string
```

[image]

---

**Filter:**

```
package org.acme;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode;
import org.eclipse.microprofile.openapi.OASFactory;
import org.eclipse.microprofile.openapi.OASFilter;
import org.eclipse.microprofile.openapi.models.Components;
import org.eclipse.microprofile.openapi.models.OpenAPI;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.eclipse.microprofile.openapi.models.PathItem;
import org.eclipse.microprofile.openapi.models.examples.Example;

import io.quarkus.logging.Log;
import org.eclipse.microprofile.openapi.models.media.Schema;

import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

public class CustomOASFilter implements OASFilter {

    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

    @Override
    public void filterOpenAPI(OpenAPI openAPI) {

        //openApi.getComponents() will result in NULL as we don't have any openapi.yaml file.
        Components defaultComponents = OASFactory.createComponents();
        if (openAPI.getComponents() == null) {
            openAPI.setComponents(defaultComponents);
        }

        generateExamples().forEach(openAPI.getComponents()::addExample);

        updateHealthStatusRefWithProgrammaticSchema(openAPI);
    }

    Map<String, Example> generateExamples() {

        Map<String, Example> examples = new LinkedHashMap<>();

        try {

            ClassLoader loader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();

            String userJSON = new String(loader.getResourceAsStream("user.json").readAllBytes(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
            String customerJson = new String(loader.getResourceAsStream("customer.json").readAllBytes(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

            Example userExample = OASFactory.createExample().description("User JSON Example Description").value(objectMapper.readValue(userJSON, ObjectNode.class));

            Example customerExample = OASFactory.createExample().description("Customer JSON Example Description").value(objectMapper.readValue(customerJson, ObjectNode.class));

            examples.put("userExample", userExample);
            examples.put("customerExample", customerExample);

        } catch (IOException ioException) {
            Log.error(ioException);
        }
        return examples;
    }

        void updateHealthStatusRefWithProgrammaticSchema(OpenAPI openAPI) {

            openAPI.getPaths().getPathItems().forEach((String pathName, PathItem pathItem) -> {
                if (pathName.equalsIgnoreCase("/health-check")) {

                    Schema dynamicSchema = OASFactory.createSchema().title("Programmatic-MicroProfile").description("dynamic-schema-description").type(Schema.SchemaType.OBJECT).properties(Map.of("custom-field-data", OASFactory.createSchema().description("Information of the service. If the service is down, this holds the information of why it is failed.").type(Schema.SchemaType.OBJECT)));
                    openAPI.getComponents().addSchema("Dynamic-MicroProfile", dynamicSchema);

                    pathItem.getGET().getResponses().getAPIResponse("200").getContent().getMediaType("application/json").setSchema(dynamicSchema);
                }
            });
        }

        void updateHealthStatusRefByUsingStaticSchema(OpenAPI openAPI) {

            openAPI.getPaths().getPathItems().forEach((String pathName, PathItem pathItem) -> {
                if (pathName.equalsIgnoreCase("/health-check")) {
                    Schema staticMicroProfileSchema = openAPI.getComponents().getSchemas().get("Static-MicroProfile");
                    pathItem.getGET().getResponses().getAPIResponse("200").getContent().getMediaType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).setSchema(staticMicroProfileSchema);
                }
            });
        }
}
```

**application.properties:**

```
mp.openapi.filter=org.acme.CustomOASFilter
```

Full-Example:

https://github.com/smustafa/quarkuks-openapi-exampleobject-loading-external-files

Comment: Thanks, will work on it.